# regex to strip number from var in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a long string and I have a var inside it

```
var abc = '123456'
```

Now I wish to get the 123456 from it.

I have tried a regex but its not working properly

```
            Regex regex = new Regex("(?<abc>+)=(?<var>+)");
            Match m = regex.Match(body);

            if (m.Success)
            {
                string key =  m.Groups["var"].Value;
            }
```

How can I get the number from the var abc?

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: Do you mean you have `String s = "var abc = '123456'";`, or you just want to convert abc to a number (e.g. `int x = Int.Parse(abc);`?

Comment: No i have var abc = '123456' inside a long string, and I want to capture 123456.  Document also has for example var dfg = '222333' and var cfg = '236789' so I want the value of var named abc

Comment: Do you want the number `123456` in string `var abc = '123456'` or all `var` string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var body = @" fsd fsda f var abc = '123456' fsda fasd f";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"var (?<name>\w*) = '(?<number>\d*)'");

Match m = regex.Match(body);

Console.WriteLine("name: " + m.Groups["name"]);
Console.WriteLine("number: " + m.Groups["number"]);
```

prints:

```
name: abc
number: 123456
```

Comment: @Johann any digit zero or more times

Comment: @Johann Refer this link for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is not correct:

```
(?<abc>+)=(?<var>+)
```

The `+` are quantifiers meaning that the previous characters are repeated at least once (and there are no characters since `(?< ... > ... )` is named capture group and is not considered as a character per se.

You perhaps meant:

```
(?<abc>.+)=(?<var>.+)
```

And a better regex might be:

```
(?<abc>[^=]+)=\s*'(?<var>[^']+)'
```

`[^=]+` will match any character except an equal sign.

`\s*` means any number of space characters (will also match tabs, newlines and form feeds though)

`[^']+` will match any character except a single quote.

To specifically match the variable `abc`, you then put it like this:

```
(?<abc>abc)\s*=\s*'(?<var>[^']+)'
```

(I added some more allowances for spaces)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var body = @"my word 1, my word 2, my word var abc = '123456' 3, my word x";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=var \w+ = ')\d+");
Match m = regex.Match(body);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example you provided the number can be gotten such as

```
Console.WriteLine (
   Regex.Match("var abc = '123456'", @"(?<var>\d+)").Groups["var"].Value); // 123456
```

\d+ means 1 or more numbers (digits).

But I surmise your data doesn't look like your example.